# I need a to send data to script with submit button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a python GUI and there I got 2 text boxes.

I want to create a submit button that will take the data from those 2 text boxes and send them to `start(save_place, website_url)` function.

This is what I got so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

def start(save_place, website_url):
    #something

app = Tk()
top_app = Frame(app)
top_app.pack()
save_location = Entry(top_app, width=20)
url = Entry(top_app, width=20)
save_location.grid(sticky=W, row=0)
url.grid(sticky=W, row=1)
save_place = save_location.get("1.0", END)
website_url = url.get("1.0", END)
button_start = Button(top_app, text="Start", fg="green", command=start(save_place,website_url))
button_start.grid(sticky=W, row=2, pady=20)
app.mainloop()
```

I also tried this:

```
from Tkinter import *

def start():
    save_place = save_loc.get()
    website_url = urls.get()
    print (save_place + " " + website_url)

app = Tk()
top_app = Frame(app)
top_app.pack()
save_loc = StringVar()
save_location = Entry(top_app, textvariable=save_loc, width=85)
urls = StringVar()
url = Entry(top_app, textvariable=urls, width=85)
button_start = Button(top_app, text="Start", fg="green", command=start)
button_start.grid(sticky=W, row=2, pady=20)
app.mainloop()
```

And it didn't work.

How can I make this script send the inputs in the text boxes to the function?

Thanks to all the helpers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous response *"about how to call a function"*, you just put `command = start` and put `save_place = save_location.get()`
 in start function, however you can use `save_location = Entry(top_app, width=20)`, so the total prg:

```
from Tkinter import *
def start():
    #something
    save_place = save_location.get()
    website_url = url.get()
    print save_place,website_url
app = Tk()
top_app = Frame(app)
top_app.pack()
save_location = Entry(top_app, width=20)
url = Entry(top_app, width=20)
save_location.grid(sticky=W, row=0)
url.grid(sticky=W, row=1)
button_start = Button(top_app, text="Start", fg="green", command=start)
button_start.grid(sticky=W, row=2, pady=20)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: try with the new edit, what you have as result when u run it?

Comment: @RonHalfon add app.mainloop() at the end as shown in my edit

Comment: I just did. Printed nothing (Its like it is 'None')

Comment: Sorry about the app.mainloop(). I did added it but because my code is long and I only get in trouble with some of it so I send the specific problem but in general I got app.mainloop() in my script. Still doesn't work

Comment: cause without app.mainloop() the main windows don't appear

Comment: try only this one and when it will be ok add the rest of your prg because this prg work well with me

Comment: I tried. When the script ended it printed empty lines. I knew it because of the '\n' that I have putted in the end of the print

Comment: OH F*** IT DID WORK!!! I DIDN'T PUTTED NOTHING IN THE TEXT BAR SO IT DIDN'T SENT IT!!! I'M SO STUPID :((((((

Answer (score 1):

`command=start(save_place,website_url)` doesn't do what you think its doing.  It's assigning the *result* of the function call to the command. (Which is probably `None`).  Bind your `Entry` boxes to `StringVar` like:

```
location = StringVar()
Entry(top_app, textvariable=location, width=20)
```

Then you assign the function call to the command parameter using `command = start`.  Inside the function you can access the value in the `Entry` using `location.get()`.  To set the value use the corresponding method `location.set(value)`

Comment: It didn't worked. Look at my edit. Maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Your function should be defined without parameters.  ie- `def start():` I tested it locally with that change and without the `font=` because I don't have that font here

Comment: OOPS. In my code it is def start() but I didn't typed it here sorry. Still doesn't work

Comment: None. It's just printing empty lines instead of what that I inserted in the text box

Comment: OH F*** IT DID WORK!!! I DIDN'T PUTTED NOTHING IN THE TEXT BAR SO IT DIDN'T SENT IT!!! I'M SO STUPID :((((((